# Cannot find module Q in build

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, jasmine-node

I run jasmine tests on Travis-CI for long, but on the latest commit I get the error `Cannot find module Q` whereas the dependency is met in package.json. if I run them locally, the tests pass well.

```
Message:
  Error: Cannot find module 'Q'
Stacktrace:
  Error: Cannot find module 'Q'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
 at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
 at require (module.js:380:17)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/CraftYourModCorporation/OpenCubes/lib/api/mods.js:18:7)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/CraftYourModCorporation/OpenCubes/lib/api/mods.js:453:4)
 at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Here is the whole project https://github.com/CraftYourModCorporation/OpenCubes.

Comment: Try lowercase -- `require "q"`. Travis-CI runs on *nix environments, where file systems are often case-sensitive. And, please include the relevant code snippets and stack traces in the question text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try lowercase `require "q"`. Travis-CI runs on *nix environments, where file systems are often case-sensitive.